# curl to get a 200 instead of 308

Tags: nginx, curl, httpresponse, http-status-codes, http-response-codes

i have a shell script to curl an url and test if it's ok.
On web browser i have no problem, i have the content i'm waiting for.

but after running this shell :

```
#!/bin/bash

URL="www.mypersonalURL.com/"
STATUS=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" $URL)
if [ $STATUS == 200 ] ; then
   echo "$URL is up, returned $STATUS"
else                     
   echo "$URL is not up, returned $STATUS"
fi
```

i always get a 308 code, what to do to make the redirection go forward and land on a 200 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not following the redirect in your curl statement. Add `-L` to your curl.

```sh
URL="www.mypersonalURL.com/"
STATUS=$(curl -L -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" $URL)
```